# How to check whether event target was inside one element or another?

Tags: angular, dom-events

I have "Card" component which is listening on outside click or scroll event and is destroyed when this event is occured.

```
@HostListener('document:mousedown', ['$event'])
public onEvent(e: Event): void {
    let el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    if (e.target !== el && !el.contains(e.target)) {
        this.destroyCard();
    }
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  document.addEventListener('scroll', this.onEvent, true);
}
```

Problem comes when from this component I create modal window which is created outside this component in app view root. When I click on modal window or scroll on it, my Card Component is destroyed along with modal window.

Here is sandbox [stackblitz with click](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tq7h2a).
When you click on modal window it should stay.

**UPDATED**. Fixed with event.stopPropagation().

But it doesn't works for such events which are not normally bubble like scroll. Please see [stackblitz with scroll](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m7gx4r).

I see only one solution: create service which will listen on events and my Card component and Modal window component will subscribe and add they nodes to array which will be checked whether event target placed inside this nodes or not.

Maybe someone know better solution?

Comment: You could listen to the `mousedown` event in the modal container, and call `$event.stopPropagation()` to prevent that event from reaching the document (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ajfcsr)).

Comment: @ConnorsFan, thank you. But this will not work, because in my case modal window is attached to DOM after Card component. So it's listener will hear event after card component listener. And event can't be stopped this way.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Since you detect the event at the document level, stopping the propagation will prevent the event from being detected. Give it a try, you will see.

Comment: Your solutions is not solved problem. I added https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tq7h2a to show what I want to implement.

Comment: In [your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tq7h2a), you call `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` instead of `event.stopPropagation()`. You can see my answer below and [the corresponding stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hx5yzg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the `mousedown` event in the modal component, and call `event.stopPropagation()` to make sure that it does not reach the `document` level. You can see the result in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hx5yzg).

```
export class ModalWindowComponent {
    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
    public processMouseDown(event: MouseEvent): void {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

**Important**: Make sure to call `event.stopPropagation()`, not `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

- `event.stopPropagation()` prevents the event from bubbling to the ancestors of the element (see [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation))
- `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` just prevents the remaining listeners on the element from being called (see [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation))

---

For the scroll event, calling `event.stopPropagation` does not work. You could keep the modal open if the scrolling element has a specific attribute, for example `data-keepmodalopen="true"` (in lower case). Here is the code for that kind of checking (see **[this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s9wtmj)** for a demo):

```
<div class="container">Modal window. I should stay
  <div class="scroll-container" data-keepmodalopen="true">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

```
public onScroll(e: MouseEvent): void {
  if (this.window && !this.keepModelOpen(e.target as HTMLElement)) {
    this.window.destroy();
    this.window = null;
  }
}

public keepModelOpen(element: HTMLElement): boolean {
  return element.dataset.keepmodalopen === "true";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer great works for click event but it doesn't cover other events which are not normally bubble like scroll. Please see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m7gx4r

Comment: I updated my answer, and added a stackblitz, to show a possible technique to solve the scrolling problem.

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you very much!

Comment: It occurred to me that the code would be simpler with a specific attribute instead of a specific class name. I updated the answer and [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s9wtmj) accordingly. The original stackblitz, which uses a class name, is available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a4b5el).